# Getting error: /tmp/tmp.0rr2YrEdc6/petalinux-env-check: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error in ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, petalinux

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5, 64 bit. While installing Petalinux (2019.1), I'm getting this error:

```
./petalinux-v2019.1-final-installer.run ../Petalinux
INFO: Checking installation environment requirements...
./petalinux-v2019.1-final-installer.run: line 183:  /tmp/tmp.0rr2YrEdc6/petalinux-env-check: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
WARNING: Please install required packages.
```

How can I resolve this Error?

Answer (score 0):

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

That means that the binary file (and therefore probably the whole package) **is not the right version for your machine**. Who knows, you downloaded the x86 package and you have a 64bit installation, or it might be for a different CPU (ARM7 for example).

Or you specified the wrong architecture when configuring. So the installer produced the binaries, but the binaries cannot run on your machine. Many packages allow this for cross-compilation.

To verify, try

```
file  /tmp/tmp.0rr2YrEdc6/petalinux-env-check
```

and (provided the temp file has not been removed) it ought to tell you which architecture etc. the binary file was made *for*.